# How to adjust/stack floating divs with dynamic height with css only?

Tags: html, css

I am having hard time to adjust floating div with dynamic heights (with CSS only) if you see the bottom gap i want them to stick together having dynamic height
please check the code here any help would be highly appreciated

```css
.c {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.D {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="D" style="height:100px; background:blue; width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:200px; background:green; width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:100px; background:pink; width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:120px; background:red;width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:200px; background:red; width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:150px; background:blue; width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:100px; background:green; width:25%;">
  </div>
  <div class="D" style="height:100px; background:pink;width:25%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to tell us what you want to achieve, what the resulting output is supposed to look like.

Comment: if you notice the gap between the divs i them want to auto adjust like tighten up no bottom gaps

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're trying to achieve?
If you end up using this approach, make sure to set the height of `.c` the sum of the two (or more) tallest, and stacked, `.D` elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/axelboberg/5pdpf6zh/

Also, try to use as little inline css as possible. It will get messy when your project grows and violates the MVC concept.